# Disconnecting a specific device connected to hotspot using command line

Tags: wireless, ap-hotspot

I have setup my Ubuntu 18.04 system as as hotspot, and there will be multiple devices connected to this setup at same time. I'm trying to write a script to remove/disconnect one of the device from the list of connected devices.

MAC and IP of the device to disconnect is known.

I'm trying to find a portable solution (which also works on other destros) for this but couldn't find one anywhere in the internet. Anyone please shed some light.